# Mass equals Moment of inertia when constant density?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass, rotational-dynamics, moment

I have found equation for moment of inertia $(J)$. I'm calculating $J$ for hemisphere, with rotational axis $Z$.

$$ J = \iiint\limits_V r^2 \cdot \rho \cdot dV $$

But if $\rho$ is constant (homogenous), I can do:
$$ J = \rho \cdot \iiint\limits_V r^2 \cdot dV $$

Which is:
$$ J = \rho \cdot V $$
$$ J = m $$

Am I right?

Comment: Tip: It is always a good idea to check if your equations are dimensionally consistent. In plain words, check what is the SI-units for moment of inertia and mass, respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. the integral $\int r^2 dV$. It is not $V$.

$\int dV$=$V$.

Answer (score 2):

No. Be careful about the integral $\int r^2 dV$. It is not $V$.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said $$\iiint _V r^2 dV \neq V$$

The volume element $dV$ in cylindrical coordinates (which is a convenient coordinate system for moment of inertia calculations) is:
$$ dV = r \, dr \, d\theta \, dz$$

There are 3 integrands ($r,\theta,z$) so you will need to integrate each with appropriate boundaries that describe a hemisphere (be careful as the $r$ above is *not* the radius of the hemisphere, but it is the $r$ in your equation!)

Comment: Hi ejrb. Welcome to Physics.SE. Indeed, it's good to help other users through answering. But while dealing with homework questions, you can always have a look at our [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/11062) on answering such questions. Please make sure that you don't give away the answer (or solve it for the author) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I'll crop this answer back to meet the guidelines